# Ajax + PHP + JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing an application using PHP, and in one of my methods I end up using an AJAX to call a PHP file. To be more specific, I'm using an each () in a div, and within that each (), I call my AJAX. The problem is that when I use AJAX the code stays in an infinite Loping.

Follow the code below...

```js
function CriarDetalhes(idPedido){
    var page = '../../../Controllers/Produtos/addDetalhes.php';

    $("#carrinho").find('.carrinho-body').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("idcarrinho");
        var valor = $(this).find(".valores").val();
        var qtd = $(this).find("#qtd_" + id).val();
        var obj = "idProd="+ id + "&valor=" + valor + "&qtd=" + qtd + "&idPedido=" + idPedido;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: page,
            data: obj,
            success: function(res){
                CriarDetalhes(res);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: I suppose if the server is returning the same 'idPedido' value, you will recurse forever because you told it to in the success handler. What does `res` equal in the success handler? The same as `idPedido`?

Comment: That really was it, it was a great lack of attention of mine. Many thanks, if you want to leave a response I will give you my ok

Comment: Glad to help. answer is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if the server is returning the same 'idPedido' value, you will recurse forever because you told it to in the success handler. What does `res` equal in the success handler? The same as `idPedido`?

If these two values are the same that is your problem.